# fb share and logo view

Tags: facebook, web, share

I have a customised button for sharing the page on fb on my website.

the html is like this:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://mydomai/Mypage.html"><div id='facebookButton' class='shareButtons'></div></a>
```

on the head I also have the following meta data:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="Images/image1.png">
```

However, even if the button works, I can't get the pic to show in the share on fb. It only gets the page name.

What am I missing please??!!

Many thanks,
Elias

Comment: without knowing your real url, it´s impossible to help

Comment: why is that? the page is www.give-net.com.

Answer (score 0):

Debug the URL: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

You will find out that there is an error:

> Object at URL 'http://www.give-net.com/' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.

There is no `og:type` tag, but it´s a required one.

You may want to read through those links:

- http://ogp.me/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

The last link is important for your `og:image` URL. Make sure it fits the aspect ratio and size recommendation.

Comment: Dear Luschn, I have done that but still does give me the pic. Any ideas?

Comment: When I debug from the facebook debugger it shows the pic. But when I click to share the pic is not there!

Comment: ok, it does look correct now, and it looks like a bug. there is "<meta property="og:image" content="Images/Art_2007_2.jpg" />" in the debugger, but you did use an absolute URL (you MUST use one). so it should actually work. sometimes the scraping is a bit buggy, you can wait for a day and hope that it´s fixed then or file a bug: developers.facebook.com/bugs